# Packaging Vue Components for npm

Tags: webpack, vue.js

I'm going to make a package for the Vue, I read [this article](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/packaging-sfc-for-npm.html), but there's an example for rollup, I'm having trouble configuring.

Do you know a good starter on the webpack(preferably using vue cli) for creating a package where you could easily configure eslint and other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use vue-cli and just bundle your project as a library.

```
vue-cli-service build --target lib --name myLib src/index.js
```

Reference https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/build-targets.html#library.